# JasperServer Deployment on Tomcat and Oracle DB (Solaris)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat5.5, jasperserver

I follow the steps of [this thread](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=54994) :

when I try to start the domain (jasperserver) I got this error in Tomcat Manager :

> FAIL - Application at context path /jasperserver could not be started

hereunder the Catalina.out log

> 2010-11-29 12:39:12,842 ERROR [/jasperserver],http-8080-Processor22:3767 - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SpringBeanServletContextPlublisher
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' [See nested exception: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']]

Comment: Oh and please edit this Q to avoid the horizontal scroll bar of doom :)

Comment: Are you trying to use mysql?  You mentioned Oracle in your headline.  It might just need the connection configuration changed.

Comment: yup, I follow the steps in this thread to change configuration to Oracle Database and I'm not willing to connect to mysql DB

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your classpath .

Comment: but I already reconfigure it to work on oracle Database & Oracle Driver , why I need Mysql Driver ?

Comment: @karimhammoda there might be some misconfiguration ,error message says  it is searching for JDBC-MySQL Driver

Comment: @karimhammoda there is some might be some network issue, check your firewall, try connecting your DB from its client,try figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can't load your JDBC driver, make suer that the JAR file representing your driver (mySQL in this case) is on your CLASSPATH (probably in the lib directory of the web/application server you are running)

Comment: 2010-11-29 19:12:53,569 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter,main:101 - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)
2010-11-29 19:12:53,582  WARN SettingsFactory,main:133 - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)

Comment: Raise that as a new question with the full stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

I must reconfigure **jasperserver.xml** file found in apache-tomcat-5.5.20/conf/Catalina/localhost  folder
the same way I reconfigure **context.xml** file in jasperserver META-INF folder